# Opening 2 text files and joining them into one

Tags: python-3.x

So I basically have 2 text files file1.txt and file2.txt in a folder and I need to join them together to make a new file3.txt. New to programming so I trying to do this using the basics. This is what I have so far

```
import os
os.listdir()
file1 = open("file1.txt")
the_file1 = file1.readlines()
file1.close()

file2 = open("file2.txt")
the_file2 = file2.readlines()
file2.close()

file3 = open("file3.txt", "w")
file3.write(the_file1 + "\n" + the_file2)
file3.readlines()
```

And I get TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list on 2nd last line so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reading both files into lists, iterate over them individually while writing into the new file

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2, open("file3.txt", "w") as f3:
    for line in f1:
       f3.write(line)
    for line in f2:
       f3.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember [readlines()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp) returns a list, so if you want to concatenate you should combine them to a string and then you can do that

```
file3.write(" ".join(the_file1) + "\n" + " ".join(the_file2))
```

`" ".join(ARRAY)` will combine the array into a single string with   as a combining character.